# How to know the version and edition of SQL Server through registry search

Tags: sql-server, wix, wix3.6

I'm using below registry search to find out if MS SQL Server 2005 having an instance named XXX is installed or not.

```
<util:RegistrySearch Root="HKLM"
                Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\XXX\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion"
                Result="exists"
                Variable="SQLServer2005"
                Value="9.00.5000.00"/>
```

How can I search the MS SQL Server 2005 edition (developer,express etc) through registry search only?

Answer (score 1):

Use below code:

```
<Property Id="SQL_EDITION">
  <RegistrySearch Id="CheckSQLEdition" Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\XXX\DTS\Setup" Name="Edition" Type="raw"  Win64="yes"/>
</Property>
```