# how to find the version and edition of sql server instance via registry

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am using below registry search to get the list of all sql server instance name.
           HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL.
How can i get the version and edition of instance name(s) return by above registry search??
What i am actually trying to accomplish here is that i want to upgrade the sql server instance (prior to version sql server 2008 R2) named say companyx (which we use for our named instance for our application ) to Sql server 2008 R2.

Comment: you don't have to go through the registry for that information - look for the SERVERPROPERTY() function

Answer (score 3):

As you state: all installed instances can be found in :

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL
```

Using the values of this instances you can go to:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\{INSTANCE DATA}\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion
```

where {INSTANCE DATA} is the data of the keys in the first registry settings.

For example: I have a computer containing this keys:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL]
"MSSQLSERVER2008"="MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER2008"
"SQLEXPRESS2008R2"="MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS2008R2"
```

=> meaning there are 2 instances:
There version can be found here:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER2008\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion]
"CurrentVersion"="10.50.4000.0"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.SQLEXPRESS2008R2\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion]
"CurrentVersion"="10.50.4000.0"
```

Comment: I know, a very late answer.  But I thought the correct answer was missing.

Comment: This only gives the GDR or Service Pack level. Applied CUs do not change this to reflect the CU version level.

Answer (score 2):

use `serverproperty()`

```
SELECT
SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS ProductVersion,
SERVERPROPERTY('Edition') AS ProductEdition

GO
```

OR try

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion
```

Comment: see here for more details http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx

Comment: thanks for replying  but i want to know ProductVersion and Edition using registry entries only...

Comment: @AbhishekKumar see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709536/how-to-know-the-version-and-edition-of-sql-server-through-registry-search

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.\Setup

Look for values of Version and Edition
-Regards

Comment: I found it under `SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Setup` as `Edition` and `EditionType` for SQL Server 1014.

Comment: That's the most complete anwser, Version and Editions found in the same place