# How to check for SQL Server database version in WIX database installer

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, wix

I have a database installer WIX tool and I want to check if SQL Server 2008 R2 is installed on the system and if it is not installed I want to show a message to install. How do I do it using WIX tool? this is my code

```html
<Property Id="SQLSERVER">
      <RegistrySearch Id="SQLServer" Root="HKLM" Key="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server" Type="raw" Win64="yes" Name="InstalledInstances"/>      
    </Property>    

    <Condition Message="You don't have SQL Server 2008 R2 installed.Please Install SQL Server 2008 R2">
      <![CDATA[SQLSERVER >< MSSQL10_50.SQLSERVER2008R2]]>
    </Condition>
```

I have added this code in product.wxs

I have a 64 bit version and when I run the installer, I'm always getting the message that the SQL Server 2008 R2 is not installed. Please let me know in order to achieve this task.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why your registry key is set to a file path in C:\ but this answer:

[how to find the version and edition of sql server instance via registry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042072/how-to-find-the-version-and-edition-of-sql-server-instance-via-registry)

indicates you should be looking at :

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\MSSQLServer\CurrentVersion

If you expect a 64-bit version then use Win64='yes'in the search (but why is your path to x86?) If the format of the version doesn't work in a property comparison, you'll need custom action code to parse it. The correct method in that answer at the link is to ask SQL directly using serverproperty, and that also requires code but is probably more reliable than the registry. It's also likely that you cannot insist on a specific version of SQL because customers use what suits them, so a more useful search might be for a minimum of Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Yes i have changed my path to registry HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server and yes i want to check for the minimum version of SQL Server 2008 installed but the Code with respect to registry search is triggered only later not in the starting. Please let me know how to trigger the code in the starting of the installation using WIX tool. Exactly where to place the code and in which file should it be Config.wxs or Product.wxs. @PhilDW